# rails 3 dynamic routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

An application I am working on in Rails 3 has a City model. Each City has a "name" column. I want this City.name to be the base url.

For example, with the City Name "Los Angeles": http://myapp.com/los-angeles.

If I use

```
match '/:name' => "cities#show"
resources :cities
```

I can get http://myapp.com/Los%20Angeles, but I need it to be 'los-angeles'.  I assume I need to change the to_params in the city.rb file.

Additionally, what should my link_to look like when this is working? Right now I am trying

```
 <%= link_to "View", city_path(:name => @city.name) %>
```

And that is giving me this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :name=>"Los Angeles", :controller=>"cities"}
```

Finally, you should note that I plan on nesting resources underneath the City in the routes so that I end up with urls like http://myapp.com/los-angeles/messages/message-content-using-to-param

etc..

Any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to handle pretty URLs with hooks into ActiveRecord(really nice by the way). This gem has nested resource support as well.

Comment: this is nice for the slugs! It doesn't do anything with my routes/link_to issue as above though.

Answer (score 1):

The method [described here](http://griffin.oobleyboo.com/archive/dynamic-routes-in-rails-redux/) would be one approach. Overriding `to_param` is also described in the [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param).

Add this to your City model.

```
def to_param
    "#{self.name_for_url}" 
end

def name_for_url
    self.name.gsub(/^A-Z0-9\-_/i,'')
end
```

This will cause `city_path(@city)` to provide  `/cities/los-angeles`

If you want City to be your root controller, in routes.rb:

```
map.root :controller => 'city'
```

Now, http://myapp.com/los-angeles should work.